# Focus modal with keyboard

Tags: gnome, keyboard, 20.04

There are at least 2 modal windows, `Run a Command` (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>) and `Authentication Required` (launch an app requiring `sudo`, e.g. Synaptic).

In both cases, there is no way I have found to focus the controls or exit before a mouse click.

Tried:

1. <kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>Tab</kbd> multiple times, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>Space</kbd>,<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, <kbd>Esc</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>.
2. Unplugging the mouse does not restore the keyboard's ability when the modal is open.
3. The Gnome extension, "Focus my window", has no effect on this.

Workaround: Click the input first.